# Implementing Google Play Games Services in Swift

Tags: ios, swift, google-play-games

Hello fellow developers :)
I have been trying to implement Google Play Games Services in my newest app project, but find myself being completely lost. I find GMS to be quite complicated and therefore need some sort of tutorial to stand a chance.

Unfortunately the official guide on Googles websites (https://developers.google.com/games/services/ios/quickstart) only describes the setup process for Objective-C.

My question is therefore, as ambiguous as is, if anyone knows anything that could help me implement GMS. This includes links to tutorials, code-snippets, personal tips, or anything else that could come in handy.

And yes, I am aware that questions like these are often frowned upon due to their ambiguous nature. What must be understood is that this question is a desperate last attempt before giving up and going with GameCenter instead. I simply have not found the information needed anywhere else.

Thank you! :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may need to use a bridging header for this. Check out the following link by gguuss in GitHub: http://github.com/gguuss/gplus-ios-swift.

Comment: Thank you very much! With that code I was able to sign in.

Unfortunately I'm still not able to convert the code required for unlocking achievements, displaying achievement, showing leaderboards, etc.

Are you able to explain how I would go about doing this, or provide links?

Comment: Nevermind, found out I was supposed to write `GPGLauncherController.sharedInstance().presentAchievementList();` to display achievements. Knowing this, the rest seems easily comprehensible.